# How can I reduce the minimum interval for periodic work requests?

Tags: android, debugging, android-workmanager

I know that there is a minimum interval of 15 minutes when requesting periodic work from a `WorkManager` and I understand the reason for that.

Yet, for debugging purposes when I want to test how some work is scheduled and run, it is **extremely annoying** to have to wait for 15 minutes to see the results. For some debugging tasks, when especially the behavior of `WorkManager` needs to be checked, it seems to be no option to use a workaround like an alarm service.

So is there a possibility to get around the minimum periodic interval only temporarily for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there a possibility to get around the minimum periodic interval only temporarily for debugging?

No, because then developers would use it for any reason.

> it is extremely annoying to have to wait for 15 minutes to see the results

Write [unit tests of your `Worker`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing-worker-impl).

Or, write [instrumented tests of your `Worker`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/integration-testing).

Or, make your `Worker` be a very thin wrapper around some other code that contains the actual business logic. Use the `Worker` for the periodic aspect, and use the wrapped code directly for debugging (e.g., temporarily hook it up to a `Button`).

Comment: Two objections: 1. I need my worker to run in background, thus I can't use a button for this. 2. corp. of evil is forcing us to use bundles, but android instrumentation have no "apk from bundle" option, so install-time features won't load (unless you copy them in main module manually each time you need instrumentation and delete - when you need to install app from AS).

Comment: Why not lift the restriction for debug builds?